# Printing on dot matrix --no character/letter spacing (Printing from java application)

Tags: java, printing

I am using `JEditorPane` for printing html. I also use Eclipse SWT browser widget with Mozilla Xulrunner. Both the printing from the editor pane and browser widget results in overlapping of letters, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: My question is how to resolve this issue (there is no spaces between letters/characters). Did you see the image?

Comment: @javaBeginner "browser widget results in overlapping of letters"

Comment: I'd say this is a problem of the printer driver.

Comment: isnt this question off the topic?

Comment: but printing from notpad and test print shows no problems

Comment: i don't know it is relating to java or printer settings

Comment: how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It is fixed.  It is relating to printer settings , have to change dots per inch...

Comment: hi @AbdulMunzeerBM , I just encounter the same problem, please show me how you resolve it

Comment: I try to contact you but it doesn't show any contact information in your profile, I hope you see this comment soon
please email me muzakki.ahmad29@gmail.com

Comment: @AhmadMuzakki Your problem fixed?

Comment: @AbdulMunzeerBM yes it's fixed, Im not familiar with windows and luckily found dpi setting on printer driver in control panel, I really confused back then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

set letter spacing using css

```
letter-spacing: 0.5pt;
```